# Will every Redux reducer be called if an action is being dispatched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

a simple question about redux. Is it true that if an action has been dispatched, each and every reducer is being called? I don't have the ability to specify one reducer function for a specific action but need to check for the action type within the reducer.

Is this correct? How do you guys take care of your reducers? Sounds to me like those functions will get pretty messy..?

Comment: routing can get pretty messy also...

Comment: This aspect of Redux is actually quite useful.  Sometimes a single action will require updates to multiple areas of the Redux store.  Since every reducer still gets called, it allows you to keep your reducers small (since they only worry about updating their part of the store), while still allowing reducers responsible for different parts of the store to react to the same action.

Comment: Well i haven't seen just one good example where somebody uses different reducer with one action. Could you provide one to make it clear?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, every reducer is called.

It doesn't get messy as reducers without actions will just default to the switch `default` case. So you don't even have to worry about it.

You can also use [combineReducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) to split your reducers in multiple functions.